# How do I create a data connection library on a SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: infopath, 2013, data-connection

I am trying to create InfoPath forms based on data connections rather than directly against a list but I am unable to find out how to create the library for storing the connections.

I found this documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772101.aspx
but it is for SharePoint 2010 but this UI has changed a lot for 2013. Has anyone does this on 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled Enterprise Site Features on the web? I have the Data Connection Library app available at the end of my 'Add an App' page (previously known as 'Create List' page).

Comment: Enterprise Site Features is and was enabled but the Data Connection Library app does not show for me. There must be something else that it requires

Comment: I needed to enable the features on existing sites and that added the Data Connection Library. Thanks for the help!